# Geofence notification not sending on transition triggers

Tags: java, android, geolocation, android-geofence, google-location-services

So I followed the Google developers guide to monitor geofence transitions and for the most part it works. I set my location and the transitions happen as they should. The problem is that it only happens on the device I setup the geofence on. For example: I have devices A and B both running the same app. On device A I setup the geofence using my current location. I get a notification on device A that I entered the geofence. Meanwhile on device B I receive no notification.

Comment: what devices and OS on it you checked?

Comment: Android lollipop

Comment: Samsung s6 and Samsung galaxy note

Answer (score 0):

So you set up a geofence on smartphone A and you expect it magically will be shared with smartphone B?

No, this is not how geofences works. They are local to the `application instance`, so nothing is visible outside of that `application instance`.

This is your, as developer, role to implement stuff which shares that geofence via some mechanism(*) with other `application instance`, register it there locally and react on the trigger.

(*) some mechanism can be Bluetooth, WiFi, cellular network, IrDa, etc.